# Injecting Jquery to an iframe

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

From a php page running on our local web server I'm opening one of our web applications in an iframe. Both the pages are hosted on the same server, so I've no cross domain issues.

Editing the page directly isn't an option, so I'm trying to inject `jquery-min.js` and  `test.js` page into the page loaded in the iframe.

I'm using the following code when the iframe has loaded. I've confirmed the `css` file is added correctly as this changes the loaded pages background within the iframe, but jquery-min.js and test.js don't appear to do anything.

```
iframe = iframeModal.body.firstChild.contentWindow.document
    
    var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
    cssLink.href = protocol + ip + "test.css"; 
    cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
    iframe.body.appendChild(cssLink);
    
    var jqLink = document.createElement("link") 
    jqLink.href = protocol + ip + "jquery-min.js"; 
    jqLink .type = "text/javascript"; 
    iframe.body.appendChild(jqLink);
    
    var jqtest = document.createElement("link") 
    jqtest.href = protocol + ip + "test.js"; 
    jqtest .type = "text/javascript"; 
    iframe.body.appendChild(jqtest);
```

test.js contains:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert ( 'Alert Test' )
})
```

Can someone advise how I can add jquery-min.js and test.js correctly to the loaded iframe page so I can run jquery in the iframe page.

Thanks

Comment: So since when are we using `link` elements to embed script resources ...? That is still the job of a `script` element, I would think.

Comment: @CBroe - I've changed this from link to script, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: Changed `href` to `src` as well ...?

Comment: @CBroe that has sorted it. Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jqLink = document.createElement("link") 
jqLink.href = protocol + ip + "jquery-min.js";
```

Script resources are not embedded using `link` elements, but `script`.

(And with `script` you need to set the `src` attribute then, instead of `href`.)